# Spark-streaming issue while writing to memory sink though the console sink works fine

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read JSON data for my project in reading streaming data  using spark-structured streaming (spark version 2.3). 
**Issue:** I am not able to query the data from the memory sink since the spark-shell hangs everytime I tried.
If I change the format to console sink,it works with expected logic. I have looked into the documentation but not able
to figure out where I am going wrong.
If I check it on spark webUI, the data is processed.
I am using this on YARN

```
SPARK_VERSION :2.3



//Reading json file from the directory
val static = spark.read.json("read directory")

//Reading schema
val dataSchema = static.schema


// COMMAND ----------

// in Scala
val streaming = spark.readStream.schema(dataSchema)
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).json("directory")


// in Scala grouping by "gt" column

val activityCounts = streaming.groupBy("gt").count()

// in Scala

val activityQuery = activityCounts.writeStream.queryName("activity_counts")
.format("memory").outputMode("complete")
.start()

activityQuery.awaitTermination()

--This is where it always gets stuck
```

Comment: Do not run Spark Streaming programs locally with master configured as "local" or "local[ 1]". This allocates only one CPU for tasks and if a receiver is running on it, there is no resource left to process the received data. Use at least "local[ 2]" to have more cores.

Comment: I am running on yarn